# Why PostAsync in Xamarin.Android doesn't work?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

When I'm using PostAsync in .net framework project it logs me in, but when I'm trying to use the same code in xamarin project it doesn't get through and it's still on login page.

```
public async static void WebScrapeData(){
    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"login", "<login>"},
        {"password", "<password>"}
    };
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
    HttpResponseMessage task = await client.PostAsync("<url>", content);
    string responseTask = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

In <...> there's actual data

Comment: Do you get any error message?And please confirm that the url is correct firstly.

Comment: When I looked at what's inside responseTask and show it as html it showed me login screen. So it's working like if content wasn't pass

Comment: The URL is correct, and I don't get any error messages

Comment: I search some info, someone said that you are using .Result or .Wait or await this will end up causing a deadlock in your code, suggest you can do this:`await client.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);` to async methods for preventing deadlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay fixed after half a month. For anyone else searching this problem it's created by visual studio emulation and to fix this you do: Project>Properties>Android Option>Advance>Http Client Implementations>Change Android to Managed.
That's it, the answer was that simple... Anyway thanks to anyone who tried to help me, even if I didn't respond to you I tried your solution.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it may be helpful to other community members, thanks.